# Which Mage: The Awakening sourcebook (if any) has info on mages' daily, non-adventuring lives?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

I've always wondered what mages in Mage: The Awakening do when they are not "adventuring". **What's Jane/John *Mage* Doe's typical day like?** Does an average mage have a day job (to earn money to stay alive - shelter, food, whatnot)? ...and so on.

I know this is a broad question, but **am looking for a broad, and preferably official answer** too - hence my request for an official source (but if there's none like that, I'd gladly read unofficial opinions as well.)

Suppose I do not own any sourcebook other than the MtA core. (If there's an answer for my question in MtA, I've missed it somehow or found it inadequate. **Please provide me with page numbers** if I'm mistaken.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When making a mage, one begins by using the **World of Darkness** core rulebook to make an ordinary person, and then apply the Awakened template atop it. Since ordinary people have day jobs to earn money to stay alive, it's fair to assume that many mages do, too.

However, as the demands of mage life — the search for secret information and the fight against the Seers and the Lie — become more onerous, many mages "drop out" of everyday life and spend more time dealing with their cabals. The political and social lives of the Awakened are extensively discussed in **Sanctum & Sigil**, which is exhaustive, if a little dull.

So: broad strokes. John/Jane Doe Magus lives a life much like yours and mine, except with the knowledge that most of what the world *is* is the creation of a hierarchy of Supernal entities bent on keeping people from achieving their birthright and potential, and with the capability of enforcing their will on the world. When they undertake actions in light of this, that's where the adventures begin.

Answer (score 5):

While not official supplements, I'd read [The Broken Diamond](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?279847-Actual-Play-Mage-The-Awakening-The-Broken-Diamond-%28contains-Reign-of-the-Exarchs) and [The Soul Cage](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?375715-Mage-The-Awakening-The-Soul-Cage) actual play threads.  The GM is a WW free lancer and I learned a lot more about the potential of Mage as well as things like your question from them (especially the first) than I did from WW books.